# FIle which included first is showing later in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

controller is below:

```
public function index(){

        $this->load->model('admin_model');

        $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->get_latest_users();

        $this->load->view('templates/adminhead');

        $this->load->view('templates/adminheader');

        $this->load->view('templates/adminsidebar');

        $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);

        $this->load->view('templates/adminfooter');

}
```

view is showing properly in browser but in source code footer is showing first then home then head file. Why this is happening?

Comment: need to see entire code and file structure

Comment: how can something be shown properly in the browser if its the wrong order in the source code? e.g. if footer is first as you said then the footer should be on the top of the page... this doesn't make any sense... otherwise I'd suggest that maybe you misnamed/flipped some files

Answer (score 2):

Problem is not clear to me.But I would do this like:
Controller Code:

```
public function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
}
public function index(){
    $data['users'] = $this->admin_model->get_latest_users();
    $data['adminhead'] = 'templates/adminhead';
    $data['adminheader'] = 'templates/adminheader';
    $data['adminsidebar'] = 'templates/adminsidebar';
    $data['adminfooter'] = 'templates/adminfooter';
    $this->load->view('admin/index', $data);
}
```

And just load them on the view.

Comment: Can I load 'admin/index' after footer and it will display as required?

Comment: I mentioned that I am not clear of your requirements.But this code will just load the 'admin/index' file with $data array which has the path of other required files and data. You have to just load the view on the index page as your requirements. Like:<?php if(isset($adminfooter)) { $this->load->view($adminfooter); } ?> . and whatever you want to load.

Comment: And also loading more than one view with a function is not wise.